# how to display newsletter popup window in center of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

i created a popup window http://daplonline.in/ newsletter popup on page load
but i have a problem this popup not display correct margin LEFT-Right
any way to display it on center of page ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, I changed tow lines in "#wd1_nlpopup" css

```
#wd1_nlpopup {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -465px;
z-index: 9999;
background: white;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", "HelveticaNeueLT", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Swap it's working but if screen size is below 1000 how to hide this popup ?

Comment: Add this it in bottom of your css
@media (max-width: 1000px)
#wd1_nlpopup {
display: none !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following styles:

```
width: 640px; /* adjust to your desired width */
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure css, you juste have, with an absolute position, to give a width to your div, and play width the half of the size like that :

`#wd1_nlpopup {
 width:920px;/** your image size **/
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-460px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

DELETE  left: 45%; from #wd1_nlpopup